# How do I prove that the given language is not recognizable

Tags: computation-theory, turing-machines, reduction

Given the following language:

Lf = { p(m) | The language of M is finite }

Is Lf recognizable? if not, prove using reduction. Otherwise, build a NDTM which recognizes it.

I'm kinda sure that Lf can not be recognized but I ain't sure how to prove it.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about computing theory and not programming. Try programmers.stackexchange.com or maybe math.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 0):

Pick a language you know is not recognizable and find a reduction to Lf. The co-halting problem, for example, is not recognizable.